Is there a bound to approximate the hypergeometric function ${_2F_1}(a,b,b-0.5,x)$?
As the title mentioned, I want to get a bound to approximate
${_2F_1}(a,b,b-0.5,x),$
upper bound is preferer.
In addition, if $a>0, b>1$, then brutle upper and lower bound can be obtained. For a lower bound,
${_2F_1}(a,b,b-0.5,x)$
$=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_l(b)_l}{(b-0.5)_l}\frac{x^l}{l!}$
$>\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(a)_l\frac{x^l}{l!}$
$={_1F_0}(a;x),$
for an upper bound,
${_2F_1}(a,b,b-0.5,x)$
$=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_l(b)_l}{(b-0.5)_l}\frac{x^l}{l!}$
$<\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a)_l(b)_l}{(b-1)_l}\frac{x^l}{l!}$
$=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(b+l)(a)_l\frac{x^l}{l!}$
$=b{_1F_0}(a;x)+\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} (a)_{l+1} \frac{x^{l+1}}{l!}$
$=b{_1F_0}(a;x)+\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} ax(a)_l \frac{x^l}{l!}$
$=b{_1F_0}(a;x)+ax{_1F_0}(a+1;x).$
However, in my exact problem, $a<0, b>0$, so that the signs of the terms within the summation alternate, therefore these bounds are not correct. Is there any way to overcome this problem?
